# List opened files

Tags: c#, windows

I've read some posts about my issue, but I haven't find a right solution.
I would have a complete list of current files in use, for example:

```
*.mp3 files opened by Windows Media Player
*.txt files opened by Notepad.exe
*.avi files opened by VLC etc...
```

With FileWatcher system I can get files that are created/modified/updated or deleted, but not opened.

How I can do it?

Comment: You mean "files in use", consider editing your post and title with this as it's more accurate description of what you're after. "opened file" might also fit but IMO is less accurate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) tool from Sysinternals to obtain that information, but I don't think you can easily do the same by code (short of reimplementing Process Explorer itself).

Comment: For the record, this capability can be found in the _Find Handle or DLL.._ item under the _Find_ menu.

Answer (score 0):

Most you can achieve with simple code is iterate over all Processes and read their `Title` - most programs will put the current file in use inside their title e.g. Notepad will have window title of "TextFile.txt - Notepad".

If you like I can pull together some quick example.

To achieve exactly what you want though, you'll have to "hook" into the processes in some low level way and see their internals - Frédéric Hamidi reply pretty much covers this.

Comment: It's ok, but if I open file with Windows Media Player I don't have this info :(

Comment: @Cecco for the Media Player you can take parts of code from here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/wmp_pinvoke.aspx I'm pretty sure that it's possible to send some message and get the "currently playing" value.

Comment: Thanks Shadow Wizard, I'll try immediately and let you know as soon as possible.

Comment: Hi, I've tried your tip but doesn't solve my problem. With this link I'm able to control WMP in remote mode. But this block me to get current file in use.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the simplest method would be to use the [Handle command-line tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) from the same people as Process Explorer.

You could maybe invoke the process from your code, and then parse the output, which is basically just a big list of open files (and registry entries) divided into sections with the process that opened the file as the header.

I think that under the hood Handle uses the NT Object Manager API, so that may be worth looking into if you need to do the whole thing yourself.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this solution but Handles needs Admin permission.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps you could request UAC elevation to grant Admin permissions? I don't know the context, so that may not be suitable, but here's a link: http://goo.gl/5FLgD